# Trouble mirroring Quickbooks with MySQL using Keith Palmer's PHP DevKit

Tags: php, quickbooks, mirror

This a strange error with the latest Quickbooks. I'm also using the latest DevKit - and I went from PHP 5.5 back down to PHP 5.3.

Basically all is set up, got the right QWC pointing to the right MySQL script. Upon the first run the tables are created in the database, but then it stops and errors out (Web Connector) with this:

```
Message:
Invalid password for username: quickbooks
Description:
QBWC1040: Web connector did not provide a valid password for the given
username. Job ending.
```

My guess is that the username and password don't make it into the `quickbooks_user` custom table.

Anyone else know of a solution or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To clarify, do both versions of PHP give this error? I don't know this system, but might it help to edit some PHP code into your question?

Comment: Both versions had given me the error, and I'm running the PHP Devkit 3.0b version. I found out that the first run creates the table then errors out, and then the next automatic run will attempt to fill some data on some tables...weird huh?

Answer (score 0):

Is the password you entered into the Web Connector the valid password? Everything seems to indicate that it isn't.

Update the password (`UPDATE quickbooks_user SET qb_password = 'your new password'`) and type the new password into the Web Connector. Make sure the username in the `quickbooks_user` SQL table matches what you had in your .QWC file too.

Then try it again.

Seems to me like you're just using the wrong password...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Keith. What I found out (I'm not sure if you're aware of it) - The first attempt to sync actually creates all the tables then errors out with that message. But in fact the passwords **are** the same. Then upon the second automatic update (has to be automatic) it actually synced **some** tables. Is there code somewhere to get full sync going? Now I'm not getting that error but it's not syncing a lot of tables...only customers, and I've added almost everything to $options.

Comment: Post your code on our forums: http://www.consolibyte.com/forum/  Nothing I can do without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two passwords; one for the framework to access the database, one for the QuickBooks user the QWC will be using to log into QB.

If the database tables were created then the DSN is OK (your DB password is correct).

I'd double check the quickbooks_user table.

Assuming the qb_username (the user the QWC will be using to log into QB) and qb_companyfile (full path to the company file) fields are correct, it's most likely your password field is wrong.

The QB user password is not stored in plain text; it's a SHA1 hash, comprised of a concatenation of the QB user's password, and a salt (look in QuickBooks.php for the constant "QUICKBOOKS_SALT".

You can manually update the qb_password field by appending the salt's string to the QB user password string, then creating a SHA1 hash of that.

Update the qb_password field with the result of the hash and you should be good to go.